# Leaflet cluster based on distance

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Is it possible to make a cluster based on the distance between each pins?

Example: 
Pins A, B, C are 50 meters apart. Since B is the middle pin and the distance between A-B and B-C are 50 meters, the 3 pins are considered as one cluster.

I was able only able to cluster pins that are close to each other by setting the max zoom to 16. Here is my code:

```
var map = L.map( 'map', {
    center: [7.2,125.55],
    maxZoom: 16,
    zoom: 11
  });

L.tileLayer( 'http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
}).addTo( map );

var myURL = jQuery( 'script[src$="map.js"]' ).attr( 'src' ).replace( 'map.js', '' );

var myIcon = L.icon({
  iconUrl: myURL + 'images/pin24.png',
  iconRetinaUrl: myURL + 'images/pin48.png',
  iconSize: [29, 24],
  iconAnchor: [9, 21],
  popupAnchor: [0, -14]
});

var markerClusters = L.markerClusterGroup({
  elementsPlacementStrategy: 'original-locations',
  showCoverageOnHover: true
});

for ( var i = 0; i < markers.length; ++i ) {
  var popup = '<b>Latitude:</b> ' + markers[i].lat + '<br/><b>Longitude:</b> ' + markers[i].lng;

  var m = L.marker( [markers[i].lat, markers[i].lng], {icon: myIcon} ).bindPopup( popup );

    markerClusters.addLayer( m );  
}

map.addLayer( markerClusters );
```